# Command prompt not opening after using net user administrator /times in PowerShell admin

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell

After I set `net user administrator /times day time` command prompt is not opening; even  after doing `net user administrator /times: all`.

Comment: The administrator user is a special user and should be disabled at all times, and left alone. Messing with the Administrator user can cause your windows to stop functioning. I have no solution for your problem though.

Comment: You say you used PowerShell and now can't use the command prompt. Are you still able to open the PowerShell terminal? If so, try running `net user administrator` and see what the "Logon hours allowed" section says.

Comment: Please provide the exact command you used.  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  It’s **time** not **times**.  With another Administrator user, provide the output, of the following command: **net user Administrator**

Comment: @Ramhound Both **times** and **time** work in this case. The bigger problem here is the space between `/times:` and `all`, as that will set the logon times to `None`.

Comment: @Worthwelle - That might be the case but the exact command used would still be helpful.